# ¿como modificar primary key en una tabla?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

este es el problema: tengo una tabla productos(con datos) y esta relacionada con la tabla detalleventa(idproducto).

¿es posible actualizar el primarykey de la tabla productos aunque ese dato ya este en uso en la tabla detalleventa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si a la hora de crear la relacion la estableciste  **ON UPDATE CASCADE** 
entonces cuando hagas cambios, estos afectaran a la foranea.

referencia:
https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx

PD: siempre puedes cambiar estas reglas, desde la vista de las relaciones de tu tabla detalle

Comment: Gracias!!! me funciono

Comment: de nada @Javier, agradeceré que marques la respuesta como correcta. Slds.